# Requiring a Hook to update on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So this is a component I have in React JS

```
const EnterSetData = ({ user_card_set }) => {
  const [cardlist, setCardlist] = useState({ data: [] });

  let setlist= useGetSetDB();

  //Save and reset form
  const sendSets = () => {   
    const dupes = findDuplicates(setlist, cardlist); 
    if (dupes.length > 0) {
     saveSets(setlist)
     setCardlist({ data: [] });
    } else {
      handleDupes(dupes);
    }
  };

useEffect(() => {
    setCardlist(card_set);
  }, [card_set]);

return (
    <>
  {cardlist.data.map((card, key) => (
            <a> .......</a>))}

        <button 
         type="button"
          onClick={sendSets}
        >
          Save Cards
        </button>
      </div>
```

The main issue is while data is saved, there is a major bug. `useGetSetDB()` is used to fetch the entire set list from an API. After saving, I use `setCardlist` to update the component state. It is here that I notice that `setlist` does not change. The new entries are not there and this causes `findDuplicates` to fail. My DB checks for duplicates, and thus console.logs will show that the inserts failed. How do I force `useGetSetDB` to update on every state change.This is `useGetSetDB`

```
const useGetSetDB = () => {
    const[state,setState] = useState([]);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        const data = await fetch("/sets");
        const res = await data.json();        
        return res;
      };
      
      useEffect(()=>{
        fetchData().then(response => {setState(response)})
      },[])

  return state
}

export default useGetSetDB;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `cardlist` to `useGetSetDB` like below

```
const [cardlist, setCardlist] = useState({ data: [] });
let setlist = useGetSetDB(cardlist); //whenever cardlist gets updated, we trigger side-effect again
```

You also need to modify `useGetSetDB` to align with state change

```
const useGetSetDB = (cardlist) => {
    const[state,setState] = useState([]);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        const data = await fetch("/sets");
        const res = await data.json();        
        return res;
      };
      
      useEffect(()=>{
        fetchData().then(response => {setState(response)})
      }, [cardlist]) //add `cardlist` to dependency list

  return state
}

export default useGetSetDB;
```